# cannot create database from ERD

Tags: erd, visual-paradigm

Ive got ERD in visual paradigm and I want to generate postgreSQL database from it.
When I try generate database Ive got error:

Fail to generate database due to no physical entity in the project. (Error Code: DB0001).

I already tried to synchronize ERD with class diagram, but it didnt help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like your ERD is either in Conceptual or Logical data model. In [Visual Paradigm](https://www.visual-paradigm.com) the generation of database is only apply to Physical data model. You can right click on the blank area of your ERD and select **Open Specification**, and then specify the **Data model** to **Physical** for [generating database](https://www.visual-paradigm.com/support/documents/vpuserguide/3563/3587/85407_generatingda.html).

[image: Changing data model of the ERD]

Or if you wish to keep your Conceptual/Logical ERD, you can then follow the video below about how to generate Physical ERD from your existing Conceptual/Logical ERD for generating database.

[How to Generate Physical ERD from Conceptual ERD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uIbyZEt4AIQ)